# How to write Angular unit test for a nested Form

Tags: angular, nested, jasmine, karma-runner, formgroups

In my angular app, I have a html which has nested form.
The data passes through MainForm to its childs.
I have a method populateForm() in MainForm.component.ts which populates values in all the forms.
I am writing unit tests for populateForm function using Jasmine and Karma.
How do I check for child form and its controls.
The test coverage report doesn't cover , this.form.controls['userInformationForm']?. and this.form.controls['userAddressForm']?.

```
Following is my unit test.

    it('should populateform', () => {
                    formvalue: {
                    userInformationForm: {
                        userName: 'John'
                    },
                    userAddressForm: {
                        usercity: 'XYZ'
                    }
                }
        expect(component.populateForm(formvalue)).toHaveBeenCalled;
    });

MainForm.component.ts
export class QuoteSubmissionStep1Component implements OnInit {
    formvalue: {
        userInformationForm: {
            userName: 'John'
        },
        userAddressForm: {
            usercity: 'XYZ'
        }
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.populateForm(this.formvalue);
    }
    populateForm(formvalue): void {             
                this.form.controls['userInformationForm']?.
                    patchValue(formvalue.userInformationForm);
                this.form.controls['userAddressForm']?.
                    patchValue(formvalue.userAddressForm);
    }
}

MainForm.html
            <form [formGroup]="form">               
                    <app-user-information [form]="form"></app-user-information>               
                    <app-user-address-form [form]="form"></app-user-address-form>
            </form>


app-user-information.component.html
<div [formGroup]="userInformationForm">            
            <mat-label class="custom-label">User Name</mat-label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="userName" matInput>
            </mat-form-field>
</div>

app-user-address.component.html
<div [formGroup]="userAddressForm">            
            <mat-label class="custom-label">User City</mat-label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="usercity" matInput>
            </mat-form-field>
</div>
```